ASP.NET Using shorthand bracket notation '[]' on an interface variable - what gets created?
Let's say you have this code:
public sealed class Test
{
    public IEnumerable<string> MyList { get; } = [];
}

What is the documentation on the concrete type of object the shorthand expression [] creates? Interfaces cannot be directly instantiated.
I would assume that using the expression [] on an IList<string> would result in a List<string>, but can we be sure about other interface types?

